# Last element of an array with function old() in blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

How do I get the last element of an array 'g3' inside old() without knowing the number of elements.

```
      <select name="g3[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1" @if (old('g3')=="1" ) {{ 'selected' }} @endif >lifting</option>
        <option value="2" @if (old('g3')=="2" ) {{ 'selected' }} @endif >jogging</option>
        <option value="3" @if (old('g3')=="3" ) {{ 'selected' }} @endif >sleeping</option>  
      </select>

      <div  {!!  old('g3')  != 3 ? '':' style="display: none"' !!}> Not to be seen</div>
```

How do I get the item selected inside div.

Comment: Could use [Arr::last](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-last)

Comment: okay, but how do i apply it inside my `div` with `old()` function to get old values of `g3`.Thanks @apokryfos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `old` value is `array`, you can use `in_array` instead.

Check `old('g3')` exists and then check `value` is in array `old('g3')`

```
<select name="g3[]" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="1" @if (old('g3') && in_array('1', old('g3')) selected @endif >lifting</option>
   <option value="2" @if (old('g3') && in_array('2', old('g3')) selected @endif >jogging</option>
   <option value="3" @if (old('g3') && in_array('3', old('g3')) selected @endif >sleeping</option>  
</select>
```

And how to get last element of array, you can try this

The array_values() function returns an array containing all the values of an array.

Tip: The returned array will have numeric keys, starting at 0 and increase by 1.

```
@if (old('g3'))
   @php
      $size = count(array_values(old('g3')));
      $lastElement = old('g3')[$size - 1];
   @endphp
   // Do something
@endif
```

Comment: I just edited, my question, how to get an item without knowing it's index in div

Comment: I just edited my answer , you can check that

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [@apokryfos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487813/apokryfos) in a comment:

> Could use [Arr::last](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-last)

```php
\Illuminate\Support\Arr::last(old('g3') ?? []) != 3
```

---

##### Addendum

Based on your comment, the demo below should be sufficient:

> that works,I have just edited my qn, how to get an item without
> knowing if it's was first,second or last when selected. inside
> div.Thanks and sorry for my English

```php
<div>
    @php($data = [1 => "lifting", 2 => "jogging", 3 => "sleeping"])

    <select name="g3[]" id="g3" multiple>
        @foreach($data as $id => $v)
            <option value="{{$id}}" {{in_array($id, old('g3') ?? []) ? 'selected' : ''}}>
                {{$v}}
            </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>

    <div style="display: {{!in_array(array_flip($data)["sleeping"], old('g3') ?? []) ? 'none': ''}};"> Not to be seen</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you do it this way, it throw Type error `end(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, null given (View: D:appname\resources\views\section.blade.php)`. Thanks @steven7mwesigwa

Comment: @GabrielRogath What do you get when you inspect `dd(old('g3'))`?

Comment: @GabrielRogath  Could you now try my edited answer?

Comment: that works,I have just edited my qn, how to get an item without knowing if it's was first,second or last when  selected. inside div.Thanks and sorry for my English

Comment: @GabrielRogath Please check the **Addendum** section in my edited answer.